# Who is the real life reflection of Sancorp?

Tags: house-of-cards

In the TV show, House of Cards, there are a number of real life reflections:

- Petrov is a reflection of Putin of Russia
- Female presidential candidates are somewhat reflections of Hilary Clinton.
- ICO is a reflection of ISIS

But I am not sure which organisation Sancorp is supposed to reflect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any indication that this is supposed to be a one-to-one analogy? Why can't it be a representative for "powerful lobbyists" in general?